# Проблема с выводом результатов поиска

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Проблема в том что , когда вводишь данные с виртуальной клавиатуры, не работает проверка на совпадения , и соответственно не выводятся результаты поиска.

Хотя поиск прекрасно работает когда вводишь данные  с физической клавиатуры...
Для сверки использовал библиотеку : Autocomplete

Подскажите пожалуйста , кто уже сталкивался , как решить эту проблему ?

Вот мой код :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {



    $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {
        var Paste = $(this).data('paste');
        $('#myinput').val($('#myinput').val() + Paste);
    });



    var projects = [{
        value: "shrek",
        label: "шрек, шрек",
        desc: "мультфильм шрек 2",
        icon: "shrek.jpg"
    }, {
        value: "рождественская история",
        label: "мультфильм рождественская история",
        desc: "мультфильм рождественская история",
        icon: "cristmas.jpg"
    }, {
        value: "ледниковый период",
        label: "мультфильм ледниковый период",
        desc: "мультфильм ледниковый период",
        icon: "lp.jpg"
    }, {
        value: "simpsoni",
        label: "симпсоны",
        desc: "описание, описание, описание...",
        icon: "simpsoni.jpg"
    }];

    $("#myinput").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: projects,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("#myinput").val(ui.item.label);
                $("#myinput-id").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#myinput-description").html(ui.item.desc);
                $("#myinput-icon").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon).fadeIn('slow');
                });

                return false;
            }
        })
        .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        };



});
```

Весь код с клавиатурой : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/58/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно не лучшее решение: добавьте в конец хэндлера кликов .mybutton

```
$('#myinput').autocomplete( "search" );
```

похоже библиотека слушает UI-ивэнты #myinput, и они не срабатывают, когда вы меняете значение поля формы через val , поэтому нужно вызвать апдэйт поиска явно.